# How to iterate for each line in a multiline tcl string?

Tags: tcl, expect

I have a string consisting of several lines:

```
set lines {
line 1
line 2
line 3
}
set lines [string range $lines 1 end-1]
```

I want to do the equivalent of the following python code:

```py
for l in lines.split('\n'):
    print('line is', l)
```

output:

```
line is line 1
line is line 2
line is line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tcl solution is essentially identical to python: use split to turn a multiline string into a list.

```
set lines {
line 1
line 2
line 3
}
set lines [string range $lines 1 end-1]

foreach l [split $lines \n] {
  puts "line is $l"
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCoQwEATv84pGvHrI@hz1IDpqIIySGU/i27PRsOypoLsom0JKyobghRUXPYQr@BS0dNNf6dSilxVxlJVRl9GBZW7cQLTskcdpQ8jiEbz9jF6GXAeO0xTV2/Waz4rulL4)

[split man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/split.html)

Comment: Note that you'll get empty values at the start and end because of the position of the braces relative to the content; they're _real_ empties in this case, but sometimes in parsing you have to ignore that sort of thing anyway. The easy way to ignore them is to start with `string trim $lines \n` before splitting.

Comment: Did you miss that my answer already uses `string range`?